# To restrict to only Upper-case or Lower-case letteres

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have this regular expression

```
^(?:0[0-9]|1[0-3])-ARID-[0-9]{3}$
```

but it matches only strings like  `10-ARID-278` but I want to that it should accept strings like `10-arid-257` too.

And *not* the strings like `10-Arid-257` or 10-ARid-257

The literal should be either *ARID* or *arid*, not the mix of upper and lower-case.

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly list both uppercase and lowercase word, combining them using `|` (meaning OR).

```
^(?:0[0-9]|1[0-3])-(?:ARID|arid)-[0-9]{3}$
```